# Combobox in Datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, combobox

I created a dynamic combobox in my DataGridview like this:

```
string strcmd2 = "Select Food_Name,Food_ID from dbo.TblFood_Food ";
Dt2 = Dbc.seletcmd(strcmd2);
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColumnAcc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
ColumnAcc.DataPropertyName = "combo";
ColumnAcc.HeaderText = "Food";
ColumnAcc.DataSource = Dt2;
ColumnAcc.DisplayMember = "Food_Name";
ColumnAcc.ValueMember = "Food_ID";
DataGridview_Food.Columns.Insert(0,ColumnAcc);
```

Now I want when user selected an item in combobox, its value emerge in another cell of datagridview. what can i do?
Thanks

Comment: You can determine what the user selected in the CellContentClick event of your DataGridview

Comment: thanks but in CellContentClick event ColumnAcc is not defined!!

Comment: @Milad but you still can get to that column like `DataGridViews_Food.Columns[index]`, or something like that

Comment: @Milad Roohi you can cast it from 'e'.... I don't think CellContentClick will work any way. Have a look at my answer, while not perfect, it seems to be the way to do it..... might give you some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //string strcmd2 = "Select Food_Name,Food_ID from dbo.TblFood_Food ";
        //Dt2 = Dbc.seletcmd(strcmd2);

        //fabricate some data....
        List<Food> Foods = new List<Food>();

        Foods.Add(new Food() { Food_ID = "0", Food_Name = "NONE" });
        Foods.Add(new Food() { Food_ID = "1", Food_Name = "Burger" });
        Foods.Add(new Food() { Food_ID = "2", Food_Name = "Fries" });

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ColumnAcc = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        ColumnAcc.DataPropertyName = "combo";
        ColumnAcc.HeaderText = "Food";
        ColumnAcc.Name = "Food";
        ColumnAcc.DataSource = Foods;
        ColumnAcc.DisplayMember = "Food_Name";
        ColumnAcc.ValueMember = "Food_ID";
        DataGridview_Food.Columns.Insert(0, ColumnAcc);

        DataGridview_Food.EditingControlShowing += DataGridview_Food_EditingControlShowing;
    }

    private void DataGridview_Food_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((DataGridView)sender).CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            ComboBox cmb = e.Control as ComboBox;
            if (cmb != null)
            {
                // remove the current event handler
                cmb.SelectionChangeCommitted -= new EventHandler(cmb_SelectionChanged);
                // now re-attach the event handler
                cmb.SelectionChangeCommitted += new EventHandler(cmb_SelectionChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    private void cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cmb = (ComboBox)sender;
        Food selectedFood = (Food)cmb.SelectedItem;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You selected item {0} ---> {1}", selectedFood.Food_ID, selectedFood.Food_Name));
    }    
}
}

class Food
{
    public string Food_Name { get; set; }
    public string Food_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to handle the `DataGridView.CellEndEdit` event. After you select an option from the `ComboBox` and leave the cell, have it update the desired cell. Let's assume the `ComboBox` column is indexed at 0 and the desired column to update is column 1:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += DataGridView1_CellEndEdit;

private void DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        this.dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value = this.dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
    }
}
```

Now let's imagine you have the following `ComboBox` items:

```
{{ Food_Name = "Apple", Food_ID = 1 },
 { Food_Name = "Steak", Food_ID = 2 },
 { Food_Name = "Toast", Food_ID = 3 }}
```

Having set the `ComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "Food_ID`: Choosing `Apple` will set the other cell value to `1`; choosing `Steak` sets the other cell value to `2`; etc. That said, if `Food_ID` is *not* the value you want to set in the other cell, then consider Monty's approach using the `EditControlShowing` event.